# pip::No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, anaconda

I followed [this tutorial](https://nitishmutha.github.io/tensorflow/2017/01/22/TensorFlow-with-gpu-for-windows.html) to install Tensorflow for Windows 10. However, I get this error. What's the cause and fix?

```
C:\Users\mona6>conda create -n tensorflow-gpu python=3.6
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\mona6\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    pip:            9.0.1-py36_1
    python:         3.6.1-0
    setuptools:     27.2.0-py36_1
    vs2015_runtime: 14.0.25123-0
    wheel:          0.29.0-py36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

python-3.6.1-0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:01  17.89 MB/s
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > activate tensorflow-gpu
#
# To deactivate this environment, use:
# > deactivate tensorflow-gpu
#
# * for power-users using bash, you must source
#


C:\Users\mona6>activate tensorflow-gpu

(tensorflow-gpu) C:\Users\mona6>pip install tensorflow-gpu
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
(tensorflow-gpu) C:\Users\mona6>conda create -n py35 python=3.5
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\mona6\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    pip:            9.0.1-py35_1
    python:         3.5.3-0
    setuptools:     27.2.0-py35_1
    vs2015_runtime: 14.0.25123-0
    wheel:          0.29.0-py35_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

python-3.5.3-0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:01  22.65 MB/s
setuptools-27. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  13.10 MB/s
wheel-0.29.0-p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  16.25 MB/s
pip-9.0.1-py35 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  12.54 MB/s
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > activate py35
#
# To deactivate this environment, use:
# > deactivate py35
#
# * for power-users using bash, you must source
#


(tensorflow-gpu) C:\Users\mona6>activate py35

(py35) C:\Users\mona6>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting tensorflow==1.1.0 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
  Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (19.4MB)
    100% |################################| 19.4MB 90kB/s
Collecting wheel>=0.26 (from tensorflow==1.1.0)
  Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
    100% |################################| 71kB 2.9MB/s
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow==1.1.0)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.10 (from tensorflow==1.1.0)
  Downloading Werkzeug-0.12.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (312kB)
    100% |################################| 317kB 3.5MB/s
Collecting protobuf>=3.2.0 (from tensorflow==1.1.0)
  Downloading protobuf-3.3.0.tar.gz (271kB)
    100% |################################| 276kB 3.8MB/s
Collecting numpy>=1.11.0 (from tensorflow==1.1.0)
  Downloading numpy-1.12.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl (7.7MB)
    100% |################################| 7.7MB 231kB/s
Collecting setuptools (from protobuf>=3.2.0->tensorflow==1.1.0)
  Downloading setuptools-35.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (390kB)
    100% |################################| 399kB 3.3MB/s
Collecting appdirs>=1.4.0 (from setuptools->protobuf>=3.2.0->tensorflow==1.1.0)
  Downloading appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting packaging>=16.8 (from setuptools->protobuf>=3.2.0->tensorflow==1.1.0)
  Downloading packaging-16.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools->protobuf>=3.2.0->tensorflow==1.1.0)
  Downloading pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
    100% |################################| 61kB 7.2MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: protobuf
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for protobuf ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\mona6\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\1b\42\a0\4c7343df5b629ec9c75655468dce7652b28026896b0209ba55
Successfully built protobuf
Installing collected packages: wheel, six, werkzeug, appdirs, pyparsing, packaging, setuptools, protobuf, numpy, tensorflow
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.3 numpy-1.12.1 packaging-16.8 protobuf-3.3.0 pyparsing-2.2.0 setuptools-35.0.2 six-1.10.0 tensorflow-1.1.0 werkzeug-0.12.1 wheel-0.29.0

(py35) C:\Users\mona6>python
Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Feb 22 2017, 21:28:42) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like Python3, python3.5 is the only version you can choose to run&install tensorflow.

more information from tensorflow official website:

```
If the following version of Python is not installed on your machine, install it now:

Python 3.5.x from python.org

TensorFlow only supports version 3.5.x of Python on Windows. Note that Python 3.5.x comes with the pip3 package manager, which is the program you'll use to install TensorFlow.

To install TensorFlow, start a terminal. Then issue the appropriate pip3 install command in that terminal. ...
```

So, I recommend `Anaconda3-4.2.0` for you, it support `Python3.5` and works on my computer both in windows and ubuntu.

here is the download link : https://repo.continuum.io/archive/

you can install Tensorflow CPU-only version by following command:

```
# pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

To install the GPU version of Tensorflow, enter the following command:

```
# pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

it may can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, way too simpler and elegant(I think)

Upgrade pip to *20+* :

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then install using(Let the system decide which version is suitable) :

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me - ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu

Comment: @jtlz2 what's your operating system, and python version ??